# Relational algebra's syntax

Tags: syntax, relational-algebra

I'm studying some SQL and wanted to know some RA.In theory I understand the operations but writing is much more difficult.

Here I have schema and data : http://s3.amazonaws.com/spark-public/db/docs/pizza.sql

I need to find all pizzas eaten by at least one female over the age of 20 by using RA.How can I write that?

Answer (score 0):

\project_{pizza}((\select_{gender='female' and age>20}person) \join Eats)